# How to set specific version of Firefox as the default browser in Windows when multiple versions of Firefox are installed?

Tags: windows, firefox

I have two versions of Firefox installed:

- version 16.0.1 in `c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox`
- version 3.6.10 in `c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 3.6.10`

In the registry, the key `HKEY_CLASSER_ROOT\http\shell\open\command` has this value:
`"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -osint -url "%1"`

However, all links are being opened in Firefox 3.6.10 not in 16.0.1. How to change the version of Firefox which is used to open `http` links?

Windows XP SP3

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a couple of keys.

Read this for detailed info: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/170215-46-default-browser-registry

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox 16.0.1 and go to Firefox button -> Options -> Advanced tab -> General tab -> Click "Make Firefox the default browser" button.

Comment: This does not change **version** of Firefox used as the default browser.